# Counties are scrambled in R

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm using `ggplot2` to create a population density choropleth. It's currently working for single states, but not for multiples. It appears that the densities of various counties (that often have the same name) get mixed up, and sometimes even non-name matching counties are mixed up between states. For example, "New Jersey" gives the correct densities, but "New Jersey", "New York" tells me that the very populous Essex County in NJ has a density <30p/mi^2. Why is this?

```
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(maps)

popdensitymap <- function(...){
path <- "U:/maps-county2011.csv"

states <- list(...)
countydata <- read.csv(path, sep=",")

countydata <- data.frame(countydata$X, countydata$Population.Density)
names(countydata) <- c("fips", "density")

data(county.fips)

cdata <- countydata
cdata$fips <- gsub("^0", "", cdata$fips)
countyinfo <- merge(cdata, county.fips, by.x="fips", by.y="fips")

countyinfo <- data.frame(countyinfo, str_split_fixed(countyinfo$polyname, ",", 2))
names(countyinfo) <- c('fips', 'density', 'polyname', 'state', 'county')
countyshapes <- map_data("county", states)
countyshapes <- merge(countyshapes, countyinfo, by.x="subregion", by.y="county")
choropleth <- countyshapes
choropleth <- choropleth[order(choropleth$order), ]
choropleth$density_d <- cut(choropleth$density, breaks=c(0,30,100,300,500,1000,3000,5000,100000))

state_df <- map_data("state", states)
density_d <- choropleth$density_d  
choropleth <- choropleth[choropleth$state %in% tolower(states),]


p <- ggplot(choropleth, aes(long, lat, group=group))
p <- p + geom_polygon(aes(fill=density_d), colour=alpha("white", 1/2), size=0.2)
p <- p + geom_polygon(data = state_df, colour="black", fill = NA)
p <- p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="PuRd")
p
}
```

To use,

```
popdensitymap("New Jersey")
popdensitymap("New York", "New Jersey")
```

[Here is the csv.](http://www.census.gov/popest/data/maps/2011/maps-county2011.csv) It is very ugly, but I do not have access to a file sharing system right now.

Here is an example of the output. As you can see, the extremely populous Essex County by New York City is inaccurately represented. [image]

EDIT: [Here is my version of the CSV.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jx2c93a7gn3ksr4/maps-county2011.csv) Sorry for the dropbox delay.

Comment: Your csv file does not read in properly. It appears to have a header title (?!) and even when this is removed the field names are incorrect.

Comment: @geotheory that's strange, it works fine for me. I deleted everything up to the `,,,2010,2011,Number,Percent,Number,Percent,Population Density,Area (Square Miles),,,,` line and the lines at the bottom.

Comment: Not reproducible. If I copy, paste and run with `popdensitymap("New Jersey")` I get `Error in data.frame(countydata$X, countydata$Population.Density) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3284, 0`. For one thing, looks like there's a typo in your `breaks` argument to `cut`, last value should be `10000` not `100000`? Out of interest, does the code work if you strip it out of the function? I put together a choropleth to check and the population data and map polygons are fine so it's definitely your code.

Comment: @SlowLearner I added my cropped version of the CSV. Is it still reproducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I actually got it. SlowLearner and shujaa made me realize the problem was that counties in different states with the same names were not being assigned the right population densities.

To counter this, the merging is now done by `polyname`, meaning the `polyname` in `countyinfo` need not be changed and a `polyname` is added to `countyshapes` like so:

```
countyshapes$polyname <- paste(countyshapes$region, countyshapes$subregion, sep=",")
```

Thanks for the help. I'm not sure whether I should delete the question or leave it up for reference.

Comment: I would leave it. Although to be honest I found it quite a messy question to deal with, `merge` in the context of GIS tasks does generate problems for people and the answer may well help somebody else. Thanks for posting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to demonstrate that a simpler example seems to work...

[image: new jersey]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(maps)

csv.file <- "http://www.census.gov/popest/data/maps/2011/maps-county2011.csv"

mydf <- read.csv(csv.file, skip = 4, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
mydf <- mydf[, c(1, 2, 5, 10, 11)] # we can drop most columns

colnames(mydf) <- c("code", "subregion", "population", "density", "area")
mydf$population <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", mydf$population)) # remove commas
mydf$area <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", mydf$area)) # remove commas

nj.pop <- mydf[substr(mydf$code, 1, 3) == '340', ] # new jersey code is 34000
nj.pop <- nj.pop[2:nrow(nj.pop), ] # drop first row i.e. new jersey state itself
nj.pop$subregion <- tolower(gsub(" County", "", nj.pop$subregion))
nj.pop$subregion <- gsub("\\.", "", nj.pop$subregion)
nj.pop$density_d <- cut(nj.pop$density,
                        breaks = c(0,30,100,300,500,1000,3000,5000,100000),
                        dig.lab = 6, include.lowest = TRUE)

nj.pop

nj.shp <- map_data("county") # grab...
nj.shp <- nj.shp[nj.shp$region == 'new jersey', ] # ...and subset

identical(unique(nj.shp2$subregion), unique(nj.pop$subregion)) # should be TRUE

nj.both <- merge(nj.pop, nj.shp2, by = "subregion")

p <- ggplot(nj.both, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill = density_d), colour = alpha("white", 1/2),
                 size = 0.2) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuRd") +
    coord_equal()

print(p)
```

Comment: Exactly. The single-state examples do work. The issue occurs when multiple states are used. I'll try `sort=FALSE` as you suggested below.

Comment: I feel like the problem might be from the merge. Merging by `subregion` alone with multiple states with repeat county names could be confusing it and assigning the same density to counties with the same names since it doesn't know which region each subregion belongs to. Is there a way to merge with multiple criteria? I suppose using fips data would prevent this, but how do I add fips numbers to `map_data` without running into the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems making maps and using `merge`, because `merge` doesn't necessarily preserve the order of rows in the first data.frame. My solution has been to use `plyr::join` instead (which also tends to be faster).

The one downside is the columns you join on need to have the same names in both data frames. From `?join`:

> Unlike merge, [join] preserves the order of x no matter what join type is
>   used. If needed, rows from y will be added to the bottom. Join is
>   often faster than merge, although it is somewhat less featureful - it
>   currently offers no way to rename output or merge on different
>   variables in the x and y data frames.

Comment: `merge` with `sort = FALSE` can sometimes fix that kind of [problem](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37204/what-is-the-cause-of-tearing-of-polygons-artifacts-using-r-ggplot-and-geom).